# Arithmetic expression grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar

I'm trying to create an appropriate grammer for some arithmetic expressions. The valid tokens for my expressions are the following:

`'+', '-', '/', '*'`, and `'**'` for powers. The expressions could also contain symbols and functions. The functions can take multiple arguments, some of which might be optional. From what little I remember from expression parsing, I must come up with a grammar that is not left-recursive and also preserves operator associativity.

So here is what I came up with, after a little bit of searching (though not sure about associativity):

```
E = T Eopt
Eopt = '+' T Eopt | '-' T Eopt | ε 
T = F Topt
Topt = '*' F Topt | '/' F Topt | ε
F = Number | '(' E ')'
```

which can be found in many textbooks. What changes does the above grammar need, so that it can acommodate the power token ('**') and both symbols and functions ?

Please do not point me to flex/yacc etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  Changes begin at F:

```
E = T Eopt
Eopt = '+' T Eopt | '-' T Eopt | ε 
T = F Topt
Topt = '*' F Topt | '/' F Topt | ε
F = P Fopt
Fopt = '**' P Fopt | ε
P = Number | '(' E ')'
```

This assumes your tokenizer is distinguishing between `*` and `**`.

Comment: Should P accomodate symbols and functions then ?

Comment: @John: Yes.  Add ... | ID |  ID '(' ')' | ID '(' args ')' to P; add new rule ARGS = expression |  ARGS ',' expression ;